# Printing out values of a struct byte by byte

Tags: c

Basically, I'm trying to cast a char array to a pointer to a struct and print out the values in the struct byte by byte. This is because some legacy code I'm dealing with uses a macro to do some bitwise shifting and masking to change 4 bits within an integer in a struct, and I'm trying to find out whether the macro is working as intended. However, I've compressed my problem to this toy example-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    struct student
    {
        int32_t hi;
        int8_t test
    };

    struct student p1 = {20, 20};

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(p1); i++)
    {
        printf("%c",((char*)&p1)[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, this prints out two characters (that show up as boxes with 0014 in them) and nothing else. If I change the for loop to go from 0 to 5 (which is roughly the bounds of the for loop that I'm expecting) I get the exact same output. Is there a way to do what I want (i.e. get this to print out 5 characters)? I know that some of the characters will just be empty spaces, but I don't understand how I'm not getting said empty spaces.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The box with 0014 means character code 0x14 (20 in decimal)

Comment: Can you expalain what output you actually expected? You say "5 characters" but it's not clear which 5 characters you think should appear, or why it should be 5

Comment: The 5 characters I was expecting were some combination of empty spaces and whatever the ascii was for 20, but Basile's comment made me take a closer look at ASCII and realize that 0x00 isn't the ASCII for a space character! I'm not even sure where I got that impression. Obviously, I should've just done what dbush suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read more about [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Some characters are [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) so are not shown nicely, and your system might have some weird [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Be aware than in 2019, [UTF-8 is used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) (almost).

You'll better print your bytes in hexadecimal:

```
  printf("%02x",(unsigned int) ((char*)&p1)[i]);
```

and you might have an implementation with signed `char` -s, so it could be better to replace `char*` with an explicit `unsigned char*` (or even better `uint8_t*` from [`<stdint.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)). Notice that it is documented that [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) with `%02x` wants an unsigned integer (not simply a `char`). Anything else could be [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Refer at least to some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site, and consider looking into the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Of course, enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler (with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and use the debugger (e.g. [use `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)). So read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: should cast to `unsigned char` before `unsigned int` otherwise there will be leading F's for negative characters

Comment: No, should use `uint8_t` instead of `char`, as explained in the answer

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to print binary values as characters.  How those characters get printed depends on your console, but byte values of 0 typically don't print anything.

If you want to see what the values of the bytes are, print them as hex numbers instead:

```
printf("%02x ",((char*)&p1)[i]);
```

Comment: I would recommend, at least for readability, to cast the expression into an `int`. In principle `%02x` inr [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) expects an `unsigned int`, so technically your code is undefined behavior. Yes, I am nitpicking

Comment: Better to avoid printing `FFFFFFFF` when `((char*)&p1)[i] == -1` and use `((unsigned char*)&p1)[i]`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Casting to `int` does not mitigate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282715/printing-out-values-of-a-struct-byte-by-byte).  Using `(unsigned char*)` solves both problems.